# typescript function to delete mongodb model

Tags: mongodb, typescript

```
export function addArticle(userid: any, title: string, description: string, content: string, callback: (user: User) => void) {
    db.collection('users', function(error, users) {
        if(error) { console.error(error); return; }
        users.update(
            {_id: userid}, 
            {"$push": {articles: { title: title, description: description, content: content}}},
            function(error, user) {
                if(error) { console.error(error); return; }
                callback(user);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

I have the above typescript code which adds an article to the user model.
I want to replicate that code, but instead of adding an article I want to delete an article.

This is what i've tried, with no success:

```
export function deleteArticle(userid: any, articleid: any, callback: (user: User) => void) {
    db.collection('users', function(error, users) {
        if(error) { console.error(error); return; }
        users.update(
            {_id: userid},
            {"$delete": {articles: { _id: articleid}}},
            function(error, user) {
                if(error) { console.error(error); return; }
                callback(user);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Any thoughts on the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$delete` operator, use [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) instead:

```
users.update(
        {_id: userid},
        {"$pull": {articles: { _id: articleid}}},
        function(error, user) {
            if(error) { console.error(error); return; }
            callback(user);
        }
    );
```